# time series prediction with variable-length input

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, linear-regression, prediction

My thesis is about cancer prediction in mice. I collected data from 35 mice.  I measure the volume of the tumors every day after the beginning of cancer until the death of mice. The time of death changes between 50~72 days so I have 35-time series with different length.

I have to predict the change in the volume of the tumor over time. I want to use regression but I don't know how to fit a model for 35 time series with different length. I want to use all of the 35-time series to have a more accurate model.

notice that I can't change the length of my dataset because I lose important information about cancer behavior.

How can train a model with 35 time-series with different length? any suggestion for my problem?

Comment: Instead of using tumor volume versus days, could you use tumor volume versus fraction of total lifespan?

Comment: well, The changes in the size for every day is important for my analysis and I need to predict a value for the volume on certain days.

Comment: Could you make a useful model by truncating the number of days? That is, can you make use of a model where all data is truncated to 50 days? You might also choose all data sets that have a length of at least 60 days and truncate to 60 for a comparison model.

Comment: No, The changes in volume from the beginning of cancer until death time are important for me. I want to know what time after the beginning of cancer, the tumor reaches its maximum value.

Comment: Not just regression, I want to use a model to fit this dataset correctly. probably neural networks, ANFIS or deep learning methods.